# server push for millions of concurrent connections

Tags: xmpp, websocket, messaging, publish-subscribe, server-push

I am building a distributed system that consists of potentially millions of clients which all need to keep an open (preferrably HTTP) connection to wait for a command from the server (which is running somewhere else). The load of messages / commmands will not be very high, maybe one message / sec / 1000 clients which means it would be 1000 msg/sec @ 1 million clients. => it's basically about the concurrent connections.

The requirements are simple too. One way messaging (server->client), only 1 client per "channel".

I am pretty open in terms of technology (xmpp / websockets / comet / ...). I am using Google App Engine as server, but their "channels" won't work for me unfortunately (too low quotas and no Java client). XMPP was an option but is quite expensive. So far I was using URL Fetch & pubnub, but they just started charging for connections (big time).

So:

1. Does anyone know of a service out there that can do that for me in an affordable way? Most I have found restrict or heavily charge for connections.
2. Any experience with implementing such a server yourself? I have actually done that already and it works pretty well (based on Tomcat & NIO) but I haven't had the time yet to actually set up a large load test environment (partially because this is still a fallback solution, I'd prefer a battle hardened msg server). Any experience to how many users you get per GB? Any hard limits?

My architecture also allows to fragment the msg servers, but I'd like to maximize the concurrent connections because the msg processing CPU overhead is minimal.

Comment: This one is a tougher one to accept.  Have you considered a connectionless protocol like UDP?  You'd have to write your own ack protocols but then you wouldn't have to maintain the connections and you won't have to incur the connection overhead.  I've written some very high throughput distributed servers but not customer facing.

Comment: FYI, I have meanwhile implemented it using netty (see answer below).

Comment: Cool @Daniel.  I'll have to check it out.  I've heard good things about Netty but never used it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have meanwhile implemented my own message server using netty.io. Netty makes use of Java NIO and scales extremely well. For idle connections I get a memory footprint of 500 bytes per connection. I am doing only very simple message forwarding (no caching, storage or other fancy stuff) but with that am easily getting 1000 - 1500 msg / sec (each half a KB) on the small amazon instance (1ECU / 1.6GB).

Otherwise if you are looking for a (paid) service then I can recommend spire.io (they do not charge for connections but have a higher price per message) or pubnub (they do charge for connections but are cheaper per message).

Answer (score 3):

You have to look more in architecture of making such environment.
First of all, if you will write sockets management by yourself, then don't use Thread per Client Socket. Use Asynchronous methods for receiving and sending data.
WebSockets might be too heavy if your messages are small. Because it implements framing, which has to be applied to each message for each socket individually (caching can be used for different versions of WebSockets protocols), that makes them slower to process both directions: for receive and for send, especially because of data masking.

It is possible to create millions of sockets, but only most advanced technologies are capable to do so. Erlang is able to handle millions connections, and is pretty scalable.
If you would like to have millions of connections using other higher level technologies, then you need to think about clustering of what you are trying to accomplish.

For example using gateway server that will keep track of all processing servers. And have data of them (IP, ports, load (if it will be one internal network, firewalling and port forwarding might be handy here).
Client software connects to that gateway server, gateway server checks the least loaded server and sends ip and port to client. Client creates connection directly to working server using provided address.
That way you will have gateway which as well can handle authorization, and wont hold connections for long, so one of them might be enough. And many workers that are doing publishing of data and keeping connections.

This is very related to your needs, and might not be suitable for your solutions.

Comment: I found an interesting article for that topic: http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-1  Might be interesting to you that the autor managed to further optimize the mem footprint by using a C lib that handles the connections to replace erlang.

Comment: Maksims Mihejevs: can u pls answer of the following question, it would be helpful for me.thanks.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597203/instant-messaging-over-xmpp-or-websocket