# instant messaging over xmpp or websocket

Tags: android, ios, tcp, websocket, xmpp

i have the project requirement in which i want to make an instant messaging app in android/iphone and may be in future it supports voip and video chatting.

Now i have 2 choices

1) xmpp - it is application layer protocol for IM, which is almost 10 year old, and it has lot of extensions which support voip or may be video chatting, online/offline status and lot of other features. It is accepted by all big companies like whatsapp,fb,Skype etc

Also I heard that google has moved away from this protocol because of vulnerability.

2) websocket - it is tcp layer protocol which provides a full duplex communication over a single tcp connection and it’s new and it was standardised by IETF in 2011.i don’t know whether this protocol is mainly used for IM. but i know that it can be done as it is in tcp layer. And i didn’t saw or heard any features/extensions of web socket other than the 4 methods(i.e onOpen, onClose, onMessage and onError). so it means if i choose this i have to make my own methods of online/offline status(may be sending a frame in every “x” seconds/minute), voip, message delivery information and other features etc.

I am confused, which one i choose, xmpp or web socket, in terms of development, server handling cost, security, session handling management, browser support etc.

**If i am wrong anything about these 2 protocols then please correct me.**

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 6):

Google didn't find a vulnerability in XMPP.

You can use XMPP over WebSockets using [draft-ietf-xmpp-websocket](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-xmpp-websocket), which will soon be an RFC.

Comment: hey jeo, thanks for response, i know that it can be done using xmpp over websocket, but it is not yet been standard so thats why my senior is not focussing on this. Anyways can you please suggest from these 2 above protocol in terms of development, server handling cost etc.

Comment: I'm the co-chair of the XMPP working group.  That draft is safe to implement now, it won't have substantive change before it becomes an RFC, and is in widely interoperable production already.  You're asking about the difference between apples and fruit.